# Remove search query from url without refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, url, url-parameters, pardot

I have a simple task! I want that when I submit a form and get success or error message of the form, I go to the form directly ( using anchors ), so in order to do so, I added a parametr in my from action's URL, like that :

```
action="%%url%%?form-submitted=true"
```

And when the form is submitted I wrote this code :

```
// This script is for moving the page to the form is the page is loaded by submitting the form
let pageUrl = window.location.href;

let url = new URL(pageUrl);
let formSubmitted = url.searchParams.get("form-submitted");

if(formSubmitted){
    window.location.href = "#form-container";
}
```

The code is working perfectly fine, I am moving to my form when submitting the form, but if I scroll in the page and go check the slideshow for example, and I decide to refresh the page, the form-submitted parameter is in the URL, so when refreshing I go again to the form, which is not pleasant.

In order to fix that, I have to remove the query parameter from the URL without refreshing the page, I tried this:

```
// This script is for moving the page to the form is the page is loaded by submitting the form
let pageUrl = window.location.href;

let url = new URL(pageUrl);
let formSubmitted = url.searchParams.get("form-submitted");

history.pushstate({}, null, '');

if(formSubmitted){
    window.location.href = "#form-container";
}
```

I was excepting that to keep just my domain plus the anchor tag, but it seems like nothing is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the origin url and path only to your `url` param for `history.pushState`:

```js
let url = new URL(window.location.href);
history.pushState({}, null, url.origin + url.pathname);
```

With [history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState), you can also just use a relative url:

```js
let url = new URL(window.location.href);
history.pushState({}, null, url.pathname);
```

See also [URL Constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) (which you are using already in your example).

The reason your original code did not work is that `url` in `history.pushState()` is optional, and an empty string `''` is falsy. So in your case, since this parameter was not specified with a truthy value, it was set to the document's current URL.